# How do I pass a C# double Array to an Interface C++ function expecting a double ptr

Tags: c#

I have a Control Object that was developed in C++. The following are the declarations in C++

```
DISP_FUNCTION_ID(CSmithsPlotCtrl, "SetSpectrumData", dispidSetSpectrumData, SetSpectrumData, VT_I4, VTS_BSTR VTS_I4 VTS_I4 VTS_R8 VTS_R8 VTS_I4 VTS_PR8)

LONG  CSmithsPlotCtrl::SetSpectrumData(LPCTSTR pName, LONG yType, LONG xType, DOUBLE xBeg, DOUBLE xEnd, LONG nPoints, DOUBLE* pYData);
```

In C#, after registering the OCX file and adding the ocx as a reference and then as a component, a C# Interface file is created.

```
enter code here
[Clsid("{2636ef09-71d1-47b3-a1c8-afae9af75bd9}")]
[DefaultEvent("PointSelected")]
[DesignTimeVisible(true)]
public class AxSmithsPlot : AxHost
`enter code here`public virtual int SetSpectrumData(string pName, int ytype, int xtype, double xbeg, double xend, int nPoints, ref double pYData);
```

So how do i pass pData declared as `double[] pData = new double[5]` to parameter `pYData`

Answer (score 0):

This issue is a silent bug in the translation process.  It is silent because the pointer reference sort of has an ambiguous meaning whereas C# is highly type sensitive.  A pointer can be a pointer to a single object or it can be a pointer to an array of objects.  MSIL chose the former interpretation-that is a pointer points to a single data object.  MSIL expects developers relying on its interpretation to use the double pData[34] to indicate that an array object is to be expected.